# Unable to suspend - power manager vanished

Tags: 11.10, power-management, suspend

Recently, after a few upgrades, I find that the power-management applet indicator has
vanished, and the option of Suspend has suddenly changed to Power-off. I can still suspend
through `sudo pm-suspend`, but pressing on the Power button blanks and locks the screen at best.

Moreover, the options of Power button and Close Lid are no longer visible in Power options menu.

Comment: Can you attach screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Update `upower` from the ubuntu packages page. It needs to be updated to version 0.9.13-1 and the system did not do that automatically. You can find that here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/upower

From Terminal

```
upower -d
```

will error out. The newest version has the error fixed.

Comment: Thnx for your help. It really worked out

Comment: UPower version 0.9.13, but system doesn't restores after suspend or hibernate.
Xorg needs to be restarted.
Solution doesn't help to me.

Answer (score 0):

The options is not available in the UI anymore, but I found it to be still availble in `gconf`.

To attach an action with the power button, enter in a terminal:

> gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power
>   action_name

Where action_name is one of the following:

- suspend
- shutdown
- hibernate
- interactive (ask what to do)